# Нету нужных пакетов в pacman на Linux Manjaro

Tags: linux, manjaro

Решил установить Manjaro вместо Ubuntu, в Ubuntu в apt были пакеты "alien" и "ttf-mscorefonts-installer", а в pacman от Manjaro этих пакетов нет!
Подскажите пожалуйста что делать, заранее спасибо!

Comment: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-a-package-from-aur-on-manjaro-linux

Comment: Не находит эти пакеты(